# Set Column Equal to Another in Same Table Using Ordinal Position

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, subquery, ordinals

After adding a new column to the end of a table, I want to immediately set the values of that column equal to the values of another column in the table using only the latter's `ORDINAL_POSITION` from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table. This way, the query will not be hardcoded in the case that any existing columns do not exist in the future.

Specifically, I want to set the new column's values equal to the values of the `previous` column (in reference to `ORDINAL_POSITION`). In SQL, this means something close to the following:

```
UPDATE DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
SET    FSVAccessLvl = (
    SELECT   COLUMN_NAME        
    FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE    TABLE_CATALOG = 'DatabaseName'
    AND      TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND      TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' 
    GROUP BY ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME
    HAVING   ORDINAL_POSITION = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) - 1
)
```

Is there a way to achieve this? For a table containing *n* columns, I basically want to say `SET Col_n = Col_n-1`. Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is welcome.

Comment: You can only do this using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Using dynamic sql it should be fairly easy...

Comment: Why??? What are you really trying to do? Something about this seems horribly horribly wrong. It screams of denormalized tables. Fix the table structure and this whole problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your pseudo SQL will look something like this:

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET @New_Column = @Previous_Column
```

All you need to do is to select one row from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` that will return you a string with SQL statement and execute the result:

```
 DECLARE @sql_update VARCHAR;
 DECLARE @New_Column = 'Name_of_new_column';

 SELECT 
   @sql_update = 'UPDATE Table_Name SET ' + @New_Column  + ' = ' + @Previous_Column
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
           WHERE c.ORDINAL_POSITION < ORDINAL_POSITION
           AND c.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME
           AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = TABLE_SCHEMA
           AND c.COLUMN_NAME != @New_Column); 

 EXECUTE(@sql_update);
```